# MySQL query to get orders over two date ranges

Tags: mysql

I am trying to perform a single query to give me order totals over two date ranges for each service type

```
orderDate   serviceType revenue
2014-01-01  1           3.00
2014-01-02  2           4.00
2014-01-01  1           5.00
2014-01-03  3           3.00
2014-01-02  1           4.00
2014-01-04  2           5.00
2014-01-20  1           4.00
2014-01-21  2           5.00
2014-01-23  1           6.00
2014-01-24  3           4.00
2014-01-20  1           5.00
2014-01-21  2           6.00
```

The query to get the total number of orders and revenue for one date range is simple:

```
select serviceType, count(*) as totalOrders, sum(revenue) as totalRevenue
from   orders 
where  orderDate >= '2014-01-01' 
   and orderDate <= '2014-01-05'
group by serviceType
```

But I would like to do two date ranges in one query and get a single result like this (where totalOrders_1 and totalRevenue_1 represent the first date range and totalOrders_2 and totalRevenue_2 the second)

```
serviceType totalOrders_1   totalRevenue_1      totalOrders_2   totalRevenue_2
1           3               12.00               3               15.00
2           2               9.00                2               11.00
3           1               3.00                1               4.00
```

Comment: google this: pivot table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a join on two sub queries, like this (untested):

```
select o1.serviceType, totalOrders_1, totalRevenue_1, totalOrders_2, totalRevenue_2
from
(select serviceType, count(*) as totalOrders_1, sum(revenue) as totalRevenue_1
from   orders 
where  orderDate >= '2014-01-01' 
   and orderDate <= '2014-01-05'
group by serviceType) o1
inner join
(select serviceType, count(*) as totalOrders_2, sum(revenue) as totalRevenue_2
from   orders 
where  orderDate >= '2014-02-01' 
   and orderDate <= '2014-02-05'
group by serviceType) o2 using (serviceType)
```

Not very elegant, but a pivot solution would actually have similar processing costs.

Comment: Should work, but needs a `FROM` for the outermost `SELECT`.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ca5d6/7  (and a second date range that actually returns rows)

Comment: Yes I did add the FROM

Comment: I think this is perfect - I'll confirm and upvote in a few minutes. Thank you

Comment: Note that with this approach, it's not possible to return a row with a zero value for the count.  If there are no rows with a given serviceType within a timeframe for either of the the inline view queries (o1 or o2), the query won't return a row for the given service type. We could use an outer join operation to handle one side or the other, but there's no support for a FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

In order to include rows that have a zero count for a given serviceType for either of the periods, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT o.serviceType
     , SUM(IF(o.orderDate >= '2014-01-01' AND o.orderDate <= '2014-01-05'
             ,1,0)
       ) AS totalOrders_1
     , SUM(IF(o.orderDate >= '2014-01-01' AND o.orderDate <= '2014-01-05'
             ,o.revenue,0)
       ) AS totalRevenue_1
     , SUM(IF(o.orderDate >= '2014-02-01' AND o.orderDate <= '2014-02-05'
             ,1,0)
       ) AS totalOrders_2
     , SUM(IF(o.orderDate >= '2014-02-01' AND o.orderDate <= '2014-02-05'
             ,o.revenue,0)
       ) AS totalRevenue_2
  FROM orders o
 WHERE (o.orderDate >= '2014-01-01' AND o.orderDate <= '2014-01-05')
    OR (o.orderDate <= '2014-02-01' AND o.orderDate <= '2014-02-05')
 GROUP BY o.serviceType
```

This approach enables the return of rows like this:

```
serviceType totalOrders_1 totalRevenue_1 totalOrders_2   totalRevenue_2
4           1             111.00         0               0.00
5           0             0.00           2               444.44
```